# LyX Box frame color is brighter than expected

Tags: lyx, box

If I create a Simple Box in LyX, open its settings, and, for example, set its frame color to green, the actual color rendering is much brighter than shown in the setting dropdown. I have changed no LyX settings that could impact this. All help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you click Apply?

Comment: Yes. If I didn't, it would use the default color.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed for LyX 2.4.0, which already has a development version out although it should not be used for serious work.

The LyX display now matches the LaTeX display in terms of the color. For your use case, this means that LyX will show the "bright green" in the LyX display. The PDF output will remain unchanged. If you would like the darker green, you might need to use ERT and define a custom color.

Here is the LyX bug report that was fixed: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11828

Here is a screenshot of the lime green color in the dialog for 2.4.0dev:

[image]

Comment: This is great to know. I may have misunderstood you, but I should mention that it is showing as lime in both editing and PDF.

Comment: @Oliver the dialog (i.e., when choosing the color) now shows the lime green. I attached a screenshot.